# Electron: How to prevent Cmd + Q from quitting?

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to force the user only be allowed to quit the app from the Menu or Tray icon. I have those configured and working, but every time I hit Cmd+W or Cmd+Q it exits the app...

I tried catching it with:

```js
app.on('quit', e => e.preventDefault())
app.on('window-all-closed', e => e.preventDefault())
```

...but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: cmd+q is an OSX thing, has nothing at all whatsoever to do with electron, see here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/78948/how-to-disable-command-q-for-quit

Comment: Right, but surely it is overwriteable?

Comment: Have you tried using globalShortcut.unregister('CommandOrControl+Q') https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/global-shortcut

Comment: I would ask "why?" It's a standard way to quit applications. It's akin to overriding cmd+s to "delete everything in the doc".

Comment: Was this resolved? I also need to prevent my application from quitting with CMD+Q. The reason is, my app is "mission critical" for its application, and it's very easy for someone with fast fingers (devs are notorious) to CMD+Q and possibly not realize they're closing the wrong app. Chrome prompts me to do it a second time. I like this feature and would like to implement it in my Electron app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Menu module to override the shortcut as below:

```
const { Menu, MenuItem } = require('electron')
const menu = new Menu()

menu.append(new MenuItem({
  label: 'Quit',
  accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+Q',
  click: () => { console.log('Cmd + Q is pressed') }
}));
```

It's up to you to hide or show this menu item because 'Quit' suppose to exit the application